# Run talend job in multiple instance

Tags: talend, multiple-instances

How to run a talend job in multiple instances at the same time with different context group?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running parallel jobs in talend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309946/running-parallel-jobs-in-talend)

Comment: The thread you have referenced is about running different jobs in parallel, my question is running a single job in multiple instances at the same time.

Comment: The same way you run different jobs?  You need to be a little clearer about what the problem is that you're trying to solve.  What have you tried so far, and why didn't it work for you?

Comment: In other ETL tools, for example "Datastage". There is an option in each job to run it in multiple instance. In talend i'm not finding any option in the job properties, that's why i'm asking. The scenario is,Assume an extraction job which which has to extract the data from different schema with same table name, I would like to do this with a single job just by parameterizing the schema name and passing different values.

Comment: One way of doing this would be creating an outside job and calling the inner job with different context parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run the same Talend Job in multiple context groups as a group is a collection of context variables that are assigned to a Job.

You can run multiple instances of the same Job in a different context, by passing the context at runtime.

e.g. --context=Prod

This assumes that you have considered all other conflicts that may occur, for example, directories and files that they job may use.

I would suggest, if you have not already done this, to externalise your context values so that, when you pass your context at runtime, values are dynamically loaded and you can have different values for different context.

Answer (score 0):

Once your job is building as a jar, you can have multiple instance at the same time.