# I have to perform more stuff after the parallelization work using Talend Studio. How do I place a connecting OnSubJobOk?

Tags: talend

I am trying to implement parallelization within talend.  I have it working, but now I don't know how to connect the parallelization work to the next part.  Usually, you would click on the previous block and select OnSubjobOk.  That option doesn't appear. Is there another component that I need to add that I don't know about?

[image: Talend Parallelization Work]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the basic settings of `tParallelize` you would find the option `Wait For`. This have two options -

1. end of first subjob: sequence the relevant subjob to be executed at
   the end of the first subjob
2. end of all subjobs: sequence the relevant subjob to be executed at the end of all 
   subjobs.

So, all you have to do is connect your next part - your sub job with the `tParallelize` component by selecting the trigger - `synchronize(wait for all)`. This would ensure once all the parallel subjobs/components are executed the sub job connected with `synchronize(wait for all)` will be executed.

[image]